# How to get the string from matcher.group() and store it in separate string variable in java?

Tags: java

```
String emailAdress = "yourname@yourdomin.com";
Pattern emailAddress = Pattern.compile("(.*)(@)(.*)");
Matcher matchEmailAddress = emailAddress.matcher(emailAdress);
String secondPartOfEmail;
while(matchEmailAddress.find()){
    System.out.println(matchEmailAddress.group(1));
    System.out.println(matchEmailAddress.group(3));
}
```

When I run this source code, the output is:

> yourname
>  yourdomin.com

I want to store **yourdomain.com** in string type variable to use it later. I mean group(3) in matchEmailAddress matcher.

I've already tried:

```
String secondPartOfEmail = matchEmailAddress.group(3)
```

but a error occured.

Comment: which error occured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to match only one email address, you can do this:

```
String emailAdress = "yourname@yourdomin.com";
Pattern emailAddress = Pattern.compile("(.*)(@)(.*)");
Matcher matchEmailAddress = emailAddress.matcher(emailAdress);

matchEmailAddress.find(); //find the next substring matching your pattern
String secondPartOfEmail = matchEmailAddress.group(3);
```